# CMake try each list element to compile a file and stop at the first one working

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new to CMake(C++ in general) and currently trying some ideas that come to my mind.
However, there are some Limitations as I don't know how to solve the following question:

In my CMakeLists.txt, besides the standard

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(simple_example)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(simple_example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I want to have some new defined cache variables, e.g.:

```
ENABLE_FLAGS (default OFF)
FLAGS_LIST  (default empty_string)
```

As a User, I now want to `set(ENABLE_FLAGS ON)` and thus, my `CMakeLists.txt` should add a compiler flag from `FLAGS_LIST` to all C++ files. The `FLAGS_LIST` is a list of flags from which the `CMakeLists.txt` should select one element and stop at the first flag which works for a compilation. The List can be filled by the user. For this example, the list will be filled with x and y:

```
list(APPEND FLAGS_LIST "x")
list(APPEND FLAGS_LIST "y")
```

By trying to solve this problem on my own I came to
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -new -flags -here")`, which should allow me to set some flags.
My Initial idea was to first check if `ENABLE_FLAGS` is set to ON. If so, my `CMakeLists.txt`should try the first element of `FLAGS_LIST` (Here: x):

```
if(ENABLE_FLAGS ON)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS (list (GET FLAGS_LIST 0))
    list(POP_FRONT(FLAGS_LIST)
eńdif()
```

However, I do not know how to recursively try all other elements from the List if the first one would not work. Further what should happen if non of the user's given flags would work? Would -march=native as a "Nothing-works-so-this-is-my-standard-for-everything" do the job aswell?

Comment: "CMake try each list element to compile a file and stop at the first one working" - Iterate over list using [foreach](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html). Use [break](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/break.html) when want to stop iterations. What is wrong with that approach which is common for many languages? "Further what should happen if non of the user's given flags would work?" - It is up to you, as a project's developer, to **decide** how your project should behave in different situations. We could only help you to **implement** a particular decision.

Comment: There are scenarios where you use some logic like `try_compile(COMPILE_RESULT ...) set(SOME_FLAG) if (COMPILE_RESULT) set(SOME_FLAG ...) endif() ... target_compile_options(... ${SOME_FLAG})` any approach involving recursion seems dubious at best though. Furthermore cmake doesn't allow you to nest calls: cmake commands don't have a return value and "results" are communicated via setting a variable in the calling scope, e.g. `function(get_someval VAR) set(${VAR} "Hello world" PARENT_SCOPE) endfunction() get_someval(MSG) message("${MSG}")`